# How to list all the files in a server directory with HTTPS URL using Groovy and download the latest one?

Tags: groovy, https

I know to download a file from https using groovy we can code like below:

```
new File("output.xml") << new URL ("https://my.url/base-dir/bpjoshi.xml").getText()
```

However in my case there are multiple files in a https server directory in the format bpjoshi_ddmmyyyy.xml. I want to download the latest file from the server.

For example, if there are two files in this directory named `bpjoshi_10052017.xml` and `bpjoshi_10052016.xml,` I would like to download only the file named `bpjoshi_10052017.xml`.

Is it possible without getting a list of all files in the directory? If it's not possible, how can I get a list of all files in a https directory using groovy?

Comment: If directory listing is turned off on the server, it's not possible

Comment: Hi tim, it supports directory listing.

Comment: Hit the directory and parse the html that comes back

Comment: Thanks, @tim_yates I was able to do it by parsing the html.